# Screen flickers in response to <Super>P, can't bind it to anything

Tags: video, keyboard, shortcuts, x11

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 on ThinkPad Edge 11" and no matter what X session or wm I use, P makes widgets blank out for a fraction of a second. After a quick search through gconf and XF86 symbol tables I can't find any place where it could be bound. I believe it may have something to do with low-level support for Win+P switching video outputs on Windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is the exact same flicker as FN+F8 (switch video output). So I guess you are right with your hunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are lazy just paste this on terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/xrandr/active False
```

The <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> press is handled by gnome-settings-daemon.

Using gconf-editor, find the following conf key:

/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/xrandr/active

and set it to false (not checked). The change should be effective immediately after the edit.

[image]

References: [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/678423), [2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/539477/comments/64).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (14.04) but it could also be my environment

Comment: this does work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68463/how-to-disable-global-super-p-shortcut (possibly simply because it crashed the offending daemon, but it worked.)

Comment: For 14.10, I prefer **[this](http://askubuntu.com/a/585204/209676)** solution. You might want to keep `xrandr` functionality.