# How to disable global <Super>-p shortcut?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, xrandr, gnome-settings-daemon, media-buttons

In ubuntu 11.04 there was a workaround using gconf-editor and setting key
`/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/xrandr/active` to false.

However there is no such key in gconf-manager using ubuntu 11.10 (gnome 3).

Comment: For context, here is the [workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/20273/20358) user28503 alluded to.

Comment: The [accepted answer of @james-henstridge](https://askubuntu.com/a/68487/251379) given on 2011 suggesting the use of the `dconf-tools`, 
does not work since (at least) Ubuntu-20 (2020)-

The [reply from @Slim](https://askubuntu.com/a/1287582/251379) suggesting to use `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings switch-monitor "[]"`
works fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The new version of `gnome-settings-daemon` stores its configuration information in `dconf` rather than `gconf`.

To do the equivalent of what you were doing on 11.04, try the following:

1. Install the `dconf-tools` package, and then run `dconf-editor`.
2. In the tree on the left, navigate `org` -> `gnome` -> `settings-daemon` -> `plugins` -> `xrandr`.
3. Uncheck the `active` checkbox.

Comment: It worked nicely, thanks!
The actual name of the package is `dconf-tools`

Comment: I've fixed up the answer now.  Would you mind marking it as accepted if it solved your problem?

Comment: The way to do this from the command line is: `dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr/active false`

Comment: I found that w/ Ubuntu 13.04 it's also necessary to do `dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/active false`

Comment: In **Ubuntu 14.04** all was needed: **`dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/active false`** from the command line :)

Comment: @elgalu: doing this will disable all media keys - including volume up, down, screenshots, etc. Certainly not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yes @GuiAmbros it sucks, i still have no solution for this issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @LeoGallucci: see my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68463/how-to-disable-global-super-p-shortcut/585204#585204), or scroll down (?).

Comment: Lovely! @setempler you finally solved my Super+P nightmare

Comment: Warning for anyone considering this solution using Xenial (16.04) and using dual monitors: unchecking the `active` checkbox made it impossible for me to set correctly place the monitors (Settings -> Displays) and place the launcher on my desired monitor.

Comment: @ruquay Here's an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20273/20358) that gives more context into what's really happening, here. It notes that disabling XRandR is unlikely to work for newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: This is not working anymore on more recent gnome environments. This key does not exist anymore. org.gnome.mutter.keybindings switch-monitor is the new key holding this functionality. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1287582/938922

Answer (score 62):

On **Ubuntu 18.04**, I found two different keybindings for <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, which can be disabled with `dconf-editor`.

First, you need to install `dconf-editor`, if it's not already installed. This can be done in the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then you can launch it from the terminal:

```
dconf-editor
```

Within `dconf-editor`:

- Navigate to: /org/gnome/mutter/keybindings/switch-monitor
- If the "Custom value" field contains `['<Super>p', 'XF86Display']`, then:

  - Disable "Use default value"
  - In the "Custom value" field, type the following: `[]`
- Navigate to: /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/video-out
- If the "Custom value" field contains `'<Super>p'`, then:

  - Disable "Use default value"
  - In the "Custom value" field, delete everything.

Comment: This is just the same as the other answer.s

Comment: I don't agree. You have edited out an important info : the fact that my answer is specific to Ubuntu 18.04. Also, the accepted answer is irrelevant to 18.04, and none of the other answers fully fixes the issue with 18.04.

Comment: This worked on Bionic. Very annoying that there are two different settings for the same shrotcut. The mutter one worked for me

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually worked for me. At first i only had the media-keys/video-out disabled and it still was happening. I couldn't stand it. when I hit the combo accidentally (it's too close to my alt+p bind i use for paste mode in vim) it completely borks my multi monitor setup, requiring painful resetting.

Comment: This works on 20.04 as well.

Comment: you can keep the `['XF86Display']`

Answer (score 19):

Here's how to disable it with gsettings from your terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings switch-monitor "[]"
```

If you want to restore the shortcut

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings switch-monitor "['<Super>p']"
```

Comment: I come from a mac environment where Command + P opens vscode search panel. And in ubuntu I got frustrated cause everything it would change displays. This works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This is the answer for Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 9):

In order to **disable global `<Super>p`** keybindings, and **NOT** any other media keys (tested in Ubuntu **15.04**) I had to 'emtpy' the following dconf keys. I ran (in a terminal):

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/video-out ''
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/screenshot ''
```

Before, I searched with the next bash commands for values that contained `'<Super>p'`:

```
b="/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/"
for i in `dconf list $b | sort`; do echo -n "$i: "; dconf read $b$i; done
```

To search all `dconf` keys, use the command:

```
dconf dump / | grep '<Super>p'
```

If you want to avoid the terminal, run the program `dconf-editor` and search for the key(s) there...

**Edit:**

After some upgrades and restarts, I had the keybinding not working any more. I found, that there is/was a bug in `gnome-settings-daemon` that defines `<Super>p`. A hack is described **[here](http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-314.html)**.

In the startup process, `/usr/bin/xbindkeys_autostart` is executed on login. This script searches for the file in `$HOME/.xbindkeysrc` and loads the settings.

Since I wanted to map `gnome-screenshot -c` to `<Super>p`, I created the this file with the following content (and unmapped the settings in ubuntu/compiz):

```
# Content of $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
"gnome-screenshot -c"
mod4 + p
```

Comment: Lovely! you finally solved my Super+P nightmare

Comment: @LeoGallucci, if you have problems after restarts/updates, try the .xbindkeysrc modification (see the edit of my answer).

Comment: The [linked solution](http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-314.html) was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is still an issue as of Ubuntu 12.10 released October 18, 2012. A [bug fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/539477) for this seemed to be in the works so that at least there is an easier way to re-configure the key bindings, but it has since been marked invalid because this was supposedly fixed in `gnome-settings-daemon`.

Ultimately this problem is supposedly due to some hardware vendors hard-coding video out to <kbd>Super-P</kbd>.

There have been [updated conversations on the bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/694910) since the currently-accepted answer that suggest not turning off xrandr, but instead turning off **media-keys**:

Try the following:

1. Install the `dconf-tools` package, and then run `dconf-editor`.
2. **In the tree on the left, navigate `org` -> `gnome` -> `settings-daemon` -> `plugins` -> `media-keys`.**
3. Uncheck the `active` checkbox.

Or the command-line version of this is:

`dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/active false`

Comment: This disables a lot more than just `<super>P`. If you just want to disable that, go to the location above, find `video-out`, and just change that. Doing this answer is throwing out the baby with the bathwater.

Answer (score 5):

Even if disabling the xrandr plugin isn't working for you (like me), I suggest you to try this (it works for me):

Go in the dconf-editor via the command "dconf-editor" in a terminal, then go at:

```
/org/gnome/mutter/keybindings/switch-monitor
```

and disable "use default value" and delete:

```
'<Super>p',
```